# Django: Help using ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-models

Im new to Django and currently building an application for logging and lending of various equipment.

I have created multiple instances of my class Equipment in the database and I want to display these in my view, preferable in a list. Additionally I would like the option to select the list objects, one at a time.

As I understand, "ModelChoiceField" gets the job done, but I just don't understand how to implement it. I've read the specific documentation, but yet I've been failing for many hours and I feel really stupid.

So if someone would be so kind to give me a generic example of how to implement ModelChoiceField throughout veiws.py, forms.py, templates.html etc. I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forms.py:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    # or with some filter applied
    my_field = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Equipment.objects.all())
```

Then just use `{{ form.as_<whatever you want> }}` in your template and it should work.

Comment: Wow, I really have a tendency to overcomplicate things, haha. Thank you!